# Dialglfow V2: generate acess tocken with java

Tags: java, authentication, dialogflow-es, google-cloud-sdk

Documentation says: 
1. Install and initialize the Google Cloud SDK. 
2. Activate the service account in your local environment:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<service-account-key-file.json>
```

3. Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key.
4. For use in future shell sessions, you should save this setting in an initialization file or system setting, such as in a .bashrc file.
5. Add header: `Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)` 
    
   Is there way to generate new access token without cloud SDK, environment variables? I would like to use Java programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the documentation on using Dialogflow V2 API with different languages. Click JAVA tab for sample code in Java and expand those sections in "Before you begin" to prepare the environment.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/quickstart-client-libraries